# What are possible legal ways to obtain a textbook for free?

Tags: books

I'm not sure whether this is such a great question, and I'm not looking at illegal ways, but is there any way to obtain textbooks for free (legally)?

Answers very much appreciated.

Comment: You really shouldn't be creating 3+ accounts to ask the same question.

Comment: Are down-voters just reacting to the need for a textbook for free in academia? Anyway, the question could be probably improved with a context and motivation.

Comment: @Orion I believe the down-voters were responding to the behavior of the poster, who had created 5+ accounts and was posting nonsense answers to duplicates of this question, all now deleted.

Comment: @jakebeal I also understand how frustrating this is. But I assume the votes in this community should only reflect the value/importance/significance of questions, and should not be biased by the PO's identity or behaviour outside the question thread. This is not Faebook ;)

Comment: @Orion That's an interesting question for meta, i think: [I have opened a question on this there](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3235/22733).

Comment: Please [edit] this to show some evidence of how you have tried to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few ways that you should look into:

- Check your university library
- If your library doesn't have it, ask them about doing a interlibrary loan
- Talk to your professor. They can be insightful and understanding about these things so they might be able to lend you a copy.
- Search online for ebook/PDF versions. I found that an old edition of a statistics book was available on the author's website for free.

If you are out of options with obtaining it for free then you can usually find a used copy at your book store or online for cheaper.

Books certainly can be pricey, so in the future it helps if you factor these costs in when you apply for student loans/scholarships.

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of teaching staff: sure there are, I get them all the time.

If you are the person in charge of a university course, you can often ask the publishers for an **instructor's (or evaluation) copy**.

Some of them will only give you (time-limited) online access, some will ask you to send the book back if you don't adopt the book officially in your syllabus, but most of the times it's a free copy for good. Sometimes I even had sales reps come to my office, or send new editions to me unsolicited.

Answer (score 4):

**Move to Switzerland.** It is [legal](http://www.ip-watch.org/2014/08/06/switzerland-continues-work-on-changes-to-online-copyright-rules/) up there in the middle of the Alps to download copyrighted material for private use. The definition of "private use" includes (according to the linked article) "any personal use of a work or use within a circle of persons closely connected to each other, such as relatives or friends" and "any use of a work by a teacher and his class for educational purposes".

It is still illegal to share copyrighted material using Bittorrent, because it works in a peculiar way: it does not simply download the files, but also *uploads* parts of it for other users of the network.

Comment: Is this a "joke answer"? The cost of living in Switzerland is higher than most other countries.

Comment: You can also move to Poland, that's way cheaper.

Comment: @varun that's not usually a problem if you're earning a Swiss income...

Comment: @varun In case it wasn't clear, I don't recommend moving to Switzerland only to get textbooks. I just want to point out that in some countries downloading textbooks for study reasons *is* legal. (tomasz: I didn't know about Poland, thanks for the information).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, if I understand correctly, your emphasis is on the fact that the practice is legal in some places and not actually on moving. Since your answer had **Moving to Switzerland** (in bold and at the very beginning of your answer), I misunderstood that the key emphasis was on actually moving, which struck me as strange.

Comment: @varun A better joke answer would be "**Write the textbook!**"

Comment: @FedericoPoloni "in some countries downloading textbooks for study reasons is legal" I'm actually very interested in which countries this is allowed in. Do you know where I can find this out from? If that's too general, then what's the UK law on it?

Comment: @IrregularUser Not an expert, but the first place I'd check is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_Kingdom).

Comment: @IrregularUser Spain is another example. The legal term there is "right to private copy".

Answer (score 0):

Search around. There are initiatives distributing free (even open source) textbooks, like [Free Tech Books](http://freetechbooks.com), there are many others. Ask friendly Google.

Some people arranged with their publisher to be able to distribute their books for free, like Anderson's ["Security Engineering"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html), I know of several others. (Yes, I own that book in paper too. Two editions, even. Worth every penny.) Sometimes you'll find that the book went out of print, and the author now distributes the last edition in electronic form.

Other than that, looking around you'll find (more or less) complete lecture notes. I'm partial to [William Chen's](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/contents.html) notes on undergraduate mathematics, but there are many others. Quality (and completeness) obviously varies enormously, and sometimes you'll only find incomplete, short documents. Best of all is that rummaging around in the webpages for classes you'll often find homework and exams, likely with solutions.

If there is a (at least vaguely related) SE site, chances are that somebody already asked for free texts, search (or ask) there too.

For any more focused answers, you'll have to ask about precise contents.